# How can i get python function object from a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python functions in string format and I want to get the python objects of these functions in the scope of the program. I have tried `exec()`, `eval()` and `ast.literal_eval()` but none of these return a function object.

For example:

```
s = "def add(args):\n    try:\n        return sum([int(x) for x in args])\n    except Exception as e:\n        return 'error'\n
```

this is a simple function in string to add elements of a list. I am looking for a module of utility which can return the object of the function `add`

```
function_obj = some_function(s)
print 'type:', type(function_obj)
type: <type 'function'>
```

Comment: *Why* do you have function definitions in string format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First compile the function(**as string**) into code object ie,

```
code_obj = compile(s, '<string>', 'exec')
```

and then use `types.FunctionType` to create new function type from code object.

```
>>> import types
>>> new_func_type = types.FunctionType(code_obj.co_consts[0], globals())
>>> print(type(new_func_type))
<class 'function'>
>>> new_func_type([*range(10)])
45
```

Answer (score 3):

One way (there might be better ones - *e.g.* [[Python.Docs]: Built-in functions - compile(source, filename, mode, flags=0, dont_inherit=False, optimize=-1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) as pointed out by @Abdul-Niyas-P-M's answer) would be to:

- Use [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Functions - exec(object, globals=None, locals=None, /, *, closure=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), to execute the code, but in a restricted scope
- Wrap it in a function

> ```py
> >>> s = "def add(args):\n    try:\n        return sum([int(x) for x in args])\n    except Exception as e:\n        return 'error'"
> >>>
> >>> def create_func_obj(func_code_str):
> ...     g = dict()
> ...     l = dict()
> ...     exec(func_code_str, g, l)
> ...     if l:
> ...         return list(l.values())[0]
> ...
> >>>
> >>> func = create_func_obj(s)
> >>>
> >>> func
> <function add at 0x000002952F0DEC80>
> >>> func([1, 2, 3])
> 6
> >>>
> >>> add  # The function wasn't added in the global namespace (as an exec sideeffect)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'add' is not defined
> ```

If the code string contains other things besides the definition of **one** function, the results will not be the expected ones.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, you can give a globals dictionary to `exec`:

```
globalsdict = {}
exec s in globalsdict
```

And then globalsdict['add'] will be your function object. Globalsdict will also contain all the builtins.

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = \
'''def fun():\n
    print 'result'
'''
exec(a)

fun()
```

Comment: You should add some explanation and a link to the `exec` docs - otherwise people will recommend to delete your answer.